# How can I select which folders to sync via Exchange ActiveSync?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, exchange, active-sync

I am using Exchange ActiveSync with Android version 4.1.2, but cannot find the option to choose which folders to sync within my mailbox.  A technote on the Samsung website (albeit the US version) says this option should be there. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found sync settings for individual folders under Settings - Data Usage - then left menu softkey, make sure "Auto Data Sync" is selected.

Also, Settings -Accounts - Email - Settings -select exchange email acct, scroll down to "Exchange Active Sync Settings" lots of options for syncing, including individual sync settings for folders.